# Project lat/long to pixels

Tags: javascript, pixel, latitude-longitude, projection

I´m making an app for smartwatches, where I need to draw the track user is currently using. The track consists of lat/long pairs.

So far I´ve tried many functions, but with this one below I got most consistent results yet there are tracks, that got deformed, like squashed or the route was shifted.

```
function transformToPixels(lat, lon){
        var westLongitude = boundingBox[1].toDegrees()[1]; 
        var eastLongitude = boundingBox[0].toDegrees()[1];
        var northLatitude = boundingBox[1].toDegrees()[0];
        var southLatitude = boundingBox[0].toDegrees()[0];
        var longitudeDiff = eastLongitude - westLongitude;
        var latitudeDiff = northLatitude - southLatitude;
        var xPixel = (((eastLongitude - lon) / (longitudeDiff).toDouble()) * DISPLAY_WIDTH).toNumber();
        var yPixel = (((northLatitude - lat) / (latitudeDiff).toDouble()) * DISPLAY_HEIGHT).toNumber();
        var result = new [2];
        result[1] = xPixel - 3; //had to try/error these numbers to fit the line on the display
        result[0] = yPixel + 25; //had to try/error these numbers to fit the line on the display
        return result;
    }
```

Here is the route drawn on phone from lat/long pairs:[image: phone1]

And here is drawn on the smartwatch by projecting the same lat/long to X,Y pixels:[image: watch_wrong]

Then there is another route: [image: phone2]

And here is drawn on the smartwatch by projecting the same lat/long to X,Y pixels: [image: watch_right]

Here are the GeoJsons from which I get the lat/long pairs.

This one is working fine: https://pastebin.com/1vx8S98V
This one gets deformed: https://pastebin.com/4Mt4MpEq

I don´t need meter-perfect conversion, but the shape of the route shouldn´t be changed.

Comment: If the (in)accuracy of the GPS device is not fixed, large errors in some parts of the journey and small errors in other parts of the journey will make the path really quite uncertain. Without a perfect conversion of a person's location in the world to a GPS coordinate, how would the system prevent deformations of the path? Consider attaching images of expected and plotted path.

Comment: Hi, I´ve edited the question and added images with the source data.